# How to identify used style in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I prepared some text with style but I can find out witch style is it in style gallery (I simply forget). There is just small thumbnail without any name - how to find it, I have lots of styles. [image]

Comment: The `Styles` system is not very good in Photoshop. When you apply `Style` to a layer, the `Style` is not linked to it in any way. It just dumps all the layer styles saved in the `Style` on the layer and that's it. If you have a layer you want to copy the styles from, do this: Right-click the layer with the layer styles layer and choose `Copy layer style` and right-click another layer and choose `Paste layer style`.

Comment: Well... thank you for this, is true that I can copy layer style. But I want to find out with style is used in my text alredy. I need name. I really do :P

Comment: Sorry, but that is just not a thing in Photoshop. The connection between a style and the layer disappears as soon as you apply it.

Comment: Well so this is very stupid solution from Adobe...

Comment: It sure is. It's not the only thing in Photoshop that works like that. Swatches work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the Layer with the Style Applied and then create a New Style from it. If you need it, now you have it. You can then save your Presets and locate them in your Preset folder if you need to transfer them to others or use it on another computer.